# Is it possible to create a user who can edit component but not product in bugzilla

Tags: bugzilla

Is there a way in which we can create a user in bugzilla who can create component from a product but cannot create a product. Please help.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

1) go to "Config" -> "Users"

2) look for the user you want to

3) give permission only to "edit components"